# Determine which users are close to one user, using geolocation

Tags: node.js, dictionary, gps, geolocation

I am wondering what is the best way to determine and calculate, which users are close to one user, using geolocation and their GPS coordinates.

Given the main user GPS coordinates, I know how to calculate a "bounding box" around his position. I can store that bounding box coordinates in a database, for each user profile. But then, how can I determine which users are close to the user sending the request ?

Is there any formula that would allow me to calculate a "box" around a GPS location, given a distance, so every othe GPS position located within THAT box and applying this formula, would render the same box ?

Doing this would allow me to simply ask my database which users are pretending to be in this box.

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: I am using a MongoDB database :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gets sub documents by geoNear - MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29091420/gets-sub-documents-by-geonear-mongodb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to use the `$geoNear` aggragation provided by MongoDB.
This works perfectly, as I can set up a minimum and maximum distance.

Note that using `Mongoose` in Node.js, this functionnality is available through
`Schema.geoNear(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle your geospatial information with the help of [Geospatial Indexes and Queries](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/). If I understood you correctly, [`$geoWithin`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/#op._S_geoWithin)
can help you. This operator selects documents with geospatial data that exists entirely within a specified shape, in your case it would be the bounding box around a user position.